# Data is duplicate when using Listagg

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried many hours on this issue, my data (ONHAND NUM, PO) keep showing duplicate data, please refer to my code as below. Btw, if i remove the following code, then my ONHAND NUM & PO won't duplicate anymore, so i believe there is something wrong on these code. Please assist. Thanks.

```
    select
listagg(OH.ONHAND_REF,', ')within group(order by ES.SHPMNT_REF) as "Onhand Num",
listagg(PO.PO_ALL_TRACES,', ')within group(order by PO.PO_ALL_TRACES) as "PO"
from BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
left outer join EXPORT_ONHAND OH on ES.SHPMNT_REF = OH.SHPMNT_REF
left outer join VW_EXPORT_TRACE_PO PO on PO.FILE_NO = OH.ONHAND_REF
left outer join EXPORT_SHPMNT_CTNR CTNR on CTNR.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF
group by ES.SHPMNT_REF
```

if I remove the following code, my data will look okay without duplicate

```
  left outer join BRDB.EXPORT_SHPMNT_CTNR CTNR on CTNR.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF
```

The result i received as below

```
Onhand Num          PO
555,555,555         P0001,P0001,P0001
666,777,666,777     P0002,P0003,P0002,P0003
```

The result I want

```
Onhand Num      PO
 555            P0001
 666,777        P0002,P0003
```

Comment: You need to show us some sample data and make this a minimal and reproducible question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, I have edited my question to make it easy.

Comment: "if I remove the following code, my data will look okay without duplicate" >>> so remove it.

Comment: The problem is that the column `SHPMNT_REF` in the table `EXPORT_SHPMNT_CTNR` is not unique, so the join multiply the result. Check why to you perform the join at all, as the table is not used in the query.

Comment: @Littlefoot I need this to grab data from there

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes u are right, but the table i joined will be use in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `listagg()` doesn't support a `distinct` option.  You can work around this using window functions or by pre-aggregating along each dimension.  The latter method is more efficient, but without sample data, I am hesitant to suggest a specific query.

So, a simple enough method is to use `row_number()` and the fact that `listagg()` ignores `NULL` values:

```
select x.SHPMNT_REF,
       listagg(case when seqnum_ohr = 1 then x.ONHAND_REF end, ', '
              ) within group (order by x.SHPMNT_REF) as onhand_numbers,
       listagg(case when seqnum_pat = 1 then x.PO_ALL_TRACES end, ', '
              ) within group (order by x.PO_ALL_TRACES) as pos
from (select ES.SHPMNT_REF, PO.PO_ALL_TRACES, OH.ONHAND_REF,
             row_number() over (partition by ES.SHPMNT_REF, PO.PO_ALL_TRACES order by ES.SHPMNT_REF) as seqnum_pat,
             row_number() over (partition by ES.SHPMNT_REF, OH.ONHAND_REF order by ES.SHPMNT_REF) as seqnum_ohr
      from BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES left outer join 
           EXPORT_ONHAND OH
           on ES.SHPMNT_REF = OH.SHPMNT_REF left outer join
           VW_EXPORT_TRACE_PO PO
           on PO.FILE_NO = OH.ONHAND_REF left outer join
           EXPORT_SHPMNT_CTNR CTNR
           on CTNR.SHPMNT_REF = ES.SHPMNT_REF
     ) x
group by x.SHPMNT_REF;
```

Note that I also include `SHPMNT_REF` in the `SELECT`.  This seems like a good practice when aggregating by that column.  Of course, you don't need to include it.

I also changed the column aliases so they don't need escape characters (double quotes).  Having to escape identifiers just makes queries harder to write and to read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but i have received an error when using your code. "  "OH.ONHAND_REF" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2"." Please assist if possible, much appreciated.

Comment: @CKAng . . . Yes.  Those aliases are only known in the subquery.  I fixed the code.